# Creating mosaic dataset in Python without using ArcGIS for Desktop Standard/Advanced?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic-dataset, basic-license-level

Is there a way to create mosaic dataset via Python, numpy or gdal libraries without having a Standard/Advanced ArcGIS?

Comment: I suspect that you will be out of luck seeking an open source option because all [47 previous questions tagged `mosaic-dataset`](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mosaic-dataset) appear to be using the ArcGIS platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do mosaic using arcpy with basic license. It does not require standard/ advance ArcGIS license.

Here is a snippet of arcpy [Mosaic To New Raster](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "c:/data"
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management("land1.tif;land2.tif", "Mosaic2New", \
                                   "landnew.tif", "World_Mercator.prj",\
                                   "8_BIT_UNSIGNED", "40", "1", "LAST","FIRST")
```

Check the license information at the bottom of the help page mentioned above.

Comment: It looks like the [Mosaic](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/mosaic.htm) tool is available at all license levels too.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo. Yes, it's available in all license levels.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out this tutorial which uses the `rasterio` and `geopandas` modules and functions: https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L6/raster-mosaic.html